Why are many left-wing policies based on the view that many aspects of society behave like a zero-sum game?
Some of the positions of left-wing movements seem to have a common element, an underlying belief that many aspects of society behave like zero-sum games.
For instance:

If the rich get richer, the poor will as a result become poorer.
(Therefore, making the rich poorer will make the poor richer.)
If any responsibility is attached to a victim, the real culprit necessarily has less responsibility.
(Therefore, never even hint at blaming a victim.)
If boys are more successful at school, the girls won't learn as well.
(Therefore, giving the boys a poorer education will cause the girls to do better.)
If white people are successful in the corporate hierarchy, it causes black people to be unsuccessful.
(Therefore, bringing down the successful whites will cause the blacks to have more success.)
If children of traditional families fare well, it causes children of non-traditional families to do poorly.
(Therefore, destroying the traditional family will cause the non-traditional children to be successful.)

I'm not questioning the "if"s here; I'm concerned with the "therefore"s.
The conclusions are all based on the implicit belief that the total amounts of wealth, blame, learning, and other measures of success remain constant.
Is there a name for this ideology, or any studies explaining why some people see things this way?
NOTE: I'm trying to understand the thinking behind these views; I'm not asking for a political debate about anyone's motives or what is right or wrong.

It's not just left-wing. Conservatives think that immigrants are taking jobs away from citizens, welfare for homeless takes away from people with homes, etc. "Replacement theory" is a zero-sum idea.

@Barmar, as I said, "I'm not asking for a political debate about anyone's motives or what is right or wrong".

I wasn't giving one. It was a frame challenge that this is something specific to left-wing policies.

There are votes to close because "It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes". What would it require to make this "appear to be a good-faith effort"?

Generally speaking, left wing policies assume a non-zero sum game and right wing policies assume a zero sum game. The assumption of the post is pretty much exactly backward. Non-discrimination policies do not assume a zero-sum game.

@Barmar says "It was a frame challenge that this is something specific to left-wing policies". Yes, the question is specific to the way left-wing idealists think, that reducing the success of successful people will necessarily increase the success of currently unsuccessful people. I'm trying to understand this specific aspect of left-wing idealism. I'm certainly not claiming that the right-wing's views and positions are completely rational, or even close to rational. Are questions not allowed to be about specific political views?

I think your characterization of these attitudes is very wrong, confusing correlation with causation. Boys doing well doesn't prevent girls from doing well, but if teachers are ignoring the girls in favor of boys that will limit what the girls achieve. Rich business owners and shareholder favor paying themselves rather than their workers, so the workers can't move up.

@ohwilleke says "The assumption of the post is pretty much exactly backward.". The question is about my observation of what seems to be a common element, something I would like to understand better.  I could have mentioned many other things, such as the right-wing view that as the rich get richer, the poor will automatically also become richer, trickle-down-economics, but they would be irrelevant to this question, and in fact present the opposite view from what I am asking about. As I said, "I'm trying to understand the thinking behind these views; … not … what is right or wrong".

@Barmar says "Boys doing well doesn't prevent girls from doing well". No, but that seems to be the left's argument (which I don't care about), and it's based on learning being a zero-sum process (which is what I'm asking about).

As I said, I think you're mischaracterizing the left's arguments. And sometimes it really is a zero-sum process -- teachers only have so much attention to give to students.

Many of the people that label themselves as "Left" and also seem to be the loudest tend to use the "Oppressed" / "Oppressor" argument when discussing policies. This is zero-sum at best. I am not questioning their policies or logic. This is a simple observation. I am not saying what I think is right or wrong, just what I believe is a causation in logic.

Is this question to be taken seriously? For example:  "Therefore, destroying the traditional family will cause the non-traditional children to be successful".  Now, I don't doubt there are some people who think exactly this way.  But are they a majority or even a substantial minority of whatever is left of center of any given country?  Someone could write just as caricatural claims about "the Right" and ask about say cancelling welfare and giving a flat tax rate to billionaires and janitors.  Would you say that would be a justified characterization to base a Q on?

@Barmar said "I think you're mischaracterizing the left's arguments". Even if that were true, it wouldn't matter as far as this question is concerned. The question is about why people base their positions on zero-sum games. Even a set of totally bad examples wouldn't affect the validity of the question itself. (And IVF's answer shows that such views do exist.) ¶ So yes, down-vote the question if you think the examples are bad, but don't close it because you think I'm trying to discredit the Left.

Also, if all you wanted was to ask a "political psychology" Q, why not pick one left and one right example of zero-sum thinking?  Then you'd avoid all the contention on how it was framed.

The examples are awful and look like they really distort leftist views. Maybe concentrate on fewer examples and cite specific left and right positions on them and then analyse them with regard to zero-sum and ask for the reason. Btw. some things in politics are indeed zero -sum, others are win-win or lose-lose. That's true for the left and the right.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution suggests "fewer examples and cite specific left and right positions on them". It's because of how I arrived at the question. I was looking at various Left positions and realized that they mostly had this common factor. The Right also has views that I think are just as ridiculous, but they mostly don't have this same factor. And the question is tagged with "social-justice", something for which the Right doesn't have a lot of policies, much less zero-sum social-justice policies.

@RayButterworth The right is then known for social-injusties. It's just the same, only the other way around. The left wants to increases taxes on the rich, the right wants to decrease them. And every dollar can only be spent once. How is this in first order not exactly the same for left and right, only with reversed roles and in first order a zero-sum game. Do you think the rich deserve more money or the poor? It's your decision but the emphasis will (in first order) be on the "or".

VTD.  You have made no effort whatsoever to edit the Q from its currently hyper-pushy state.  I do think a zero-sum question, if rather abstract and theoretical, would be on topic.  There's a tie to Malthusian beliefs or the lump-labor fallacy.  And it's not like "the Left" generally shines on economics (though "the Right"'s budget balancing is nothing to crow about).  But you've populated the Q with strawmen examples and, despite being asked to, did not choose to pick any equivalent fallacy from the right (such as for example the belief that every immigrant is a net loss to citizens).

"Zero-sum thinking" is a real phenomenon, but it shows up in multiple domains. Typically, in the US the left views (abstractly) economic resources more as a zero-sum and the right views racial and immigration affairs, as well as political & economic clout along those lines as zero-sum.
I.e. in American political thought it doesn't seem to characterize one pole, but seems contextual:

The tendency to see life as zero-sum exacerbates political conflicts. Six studies (N = 3223) examine the relationship between political ideology and zero-sum thinking: the belief that one party’s gains can only be obtained at the expense of another party’s losses. We find that both liberals and conservatives view life as zero-sum when it benefits them to do so. Whereas conservatives exhibit zero-sum thinking when the status quo is challenged, liberals do so when the status quo is being upheld. Consequently, conservatives view social inequalities—where the status quo is frequently challenged—as zero-sum, but liberals view economic inequalities—where the status quo has remained relatively unchallenged in past decades—as such.

On one hand, wealth is viewed abstractly as zero-sum affair more by those who self-identify as left-wing in the US:

The two variables
of interest were respondents’ political views (“In political matters,
people talk of ‘the left’ and ‘the right.’ How would you place your
views on this scale, generally speaking?”) and their tendency to
think about the economy in zero-sum terms. This latter variable
was measured with a single item that asked respondents, on a
10-point scale, the extent to which they believe that “People can
only get rich at the expense of others” versus “Wealth can grow so
there’s enough for everyone.” [...] The more respondents identified as being on the right side of
the political spectrum, the less they viewed the distribution of wealth as
zero-sum.

However some of that goes out the window in some concrete contexts:

In the challenged status quo condition, we examined
whether participants viewed potential challenges to existing employer-employee dynamics as zero-sum (e.g., “Employees who demand
higher wages often don’t realize that it comes at the expense of their
employer’s profit margins”). In contrast, in the maintained status
quo condition, we examined whether they viewed preserving the
employer-employee hierarchy as such (e.g., “Employers who demand
higher profit margins often do not realize that it comes at the expense
of their employees’ wages”). We predicted that conservatives would
exhibit more zero-sum thinking about challenges to the status quo
but that liberals would exhibit more zero-sum thinking about moves
to preserve the status quo.
As predicted, conservatism was positively related to zero-sum
thinking when the status quo was being challenged but negatively related to zero-sum thinking when the status quo was maintained. Although participants exhibited overall more zero-sum thinking when the status quo was maintained the interaction between ideology and condition
(challenged status quo versus maintained status quo) was significant
in both studies and remained significant even when
controlling for income, socioeconomic status, and other demographics.
Thus, regardless of the issue at hand, the effect of ideology on
zero-sum thinking depends on whether the status quo is being
challenged or upheld.

Likewise if those making gains were described as immigrants

(e.g., “The wealth of a few immigrants is acquired at
the expense of many U.S. born citizens”). [...]
As expected, we found
that zero-sum thinking significantly predicted support for tough
anti-immigration policies. [...]
Compared with liberal
participants, conservatives were less prone to view economic gains
by the rich (which maintain the status quo) as zero-sum but more
prone to view economic gains by underprivileged groups (which
challenge the status quo) as such.

And this extends to things other than wealth directly, on Qs like

(e.g., “The easier it is for black students to gain admission to college, the more it becomes difficult for white students to get admitted”) [...]
“The
more influence black people have in politics, the less influence
white people have in politics,” “When black people move up in
society, they do so at the expense of white people,” and “The easier
it is for black people to get high-paying jobs, the more difficult it
becomes for white people to get the same jobs”.


World-wide, even the tendency to view wealth as zero-sum isn't universally associated with left-wing self-identification.


As for why some people (in the US at least) are more prone to this style of thinking, another paper found that individuals with a history of having ancestors enslaved or subject to the Holocaust were more prone to zero-sum thinking.

Although antebellum chattel slavery in the U.S. South was the most prevalent form of enslavement for the ancestors of U.S. citizens today, other forms of enslavement did occur, such as
the internment of Japanese and German Americans, the forced reservation of Indigenous people,
indentured servitude, and the imprisonment of Jewish ancestors in concentration camps during
the Holocaust. We find that these other forms of historical enslavement are also associated with
more zero-sum thinking today.

And this paper also attempted to discover whether a history of immigration in the respondents' area is related

We link our survey
information on where parents and grandparents grew up to county-level data on the average
shares of the population that were immigrants during the Age of Mass Migration between 1860
and 1920. We find that if the respondent’s grandparents – and, to a lesser extent, their parents
– were raised in a county with a larger share of immigrants, the respondent (their child or
grandchild, respectively) possesses a less zero-sum worldview today. This finding corroborates
the idea that the perspectives of ancestors were shaped by the newly-arrived immigrants in their
vicinity, and these views were subsequently passed on to younger generations, including the
respondent. Notably, we do not discover a correlation between zero-sum views and the 1860-1920
immigrant proportion of the county where respondents themselves grew up, suggesting that
the place-specific patterns arising from the waves of immigrants in the late 19th and early 20th
centuries may no longer be present today.

Also they conclude based on parents' vs respondents income that

greater intergenerational mobility is associated with less zero-sum thinking.

Methodologically, this paper constructs a single index of zero-sum inclination based on just 4 questions, about "the economic well-being of U.S. citizens and non-citizens, trade gains across different countries,
wealth gains of different ethnic groups in the U.S., and wealth accumulation of different income classes in the U.S". (See pp. 12-15 for the exact Qs.)
It also concludes that on this index, Democrats are somewhat more inclined to be zero-sum minded. Nonetheless they concluded that "zero-sum thinking is not primarily a partisan issue". And they also conclude that zero-sum thinking was a "strong predictor" in voting for Donald Trump, across party lines (pp. 30-32).

(1/2) TBH, this last bit [about Trump] is a slightly jarring (or at least worthy of more discussion) given the fact that Blacks and Jews mostly didn't vote for Trump, IIRC, and the paper found sub-groups of these two to have a higher inclination for zero-sum thinking on their 4Q index. The paper doesn't discuss Jews as a group [beyond the Holocaust survivors sub-group], but they do discuss Blacks overall as having (p. 5) the highest zero-sum thinking in the US (on that 4Q index).

(2/2) The paper doesn't discuss the contrast that exists with these two groups -- Jews and Blacks -- (mostly) not voting for Trump, but I suppose one may conclude that it was among the majority [Whites etc.] that those who did vote for Trump also had a higher degree of zero-sum thiking.

I guess one could also question the conceptual unity of the authors' definition of "enslavement." E.g. slavery is generally understood to imply forced labor, which chattel slavery of Black people and indentured servitude almost universally did, but while I know that forced labor did occur among prisoners in Holocaust camps in Nazi Germany or American internment camps, I'm not sure that it was as universal. And I think displacement/imprisonment without forced labor was more the rule than the exception with American reservations for Indigenous people.

Of course, maybe they're seeing the effects of imprisonment, more than forced labor or just the effects of societal oppression and exclusion generally (in specific cases involving forced labor or imprisonment). Or perhaps it is all about slavery, and descendents of enslaved Africans or indentured servants showed a greater effect because forced labor was more universal among these groups than the others.

Pseudo-answer: They don't.
Frame Challenge:
It isn't viewed as a zero-sum, but based on relative differences. I'm not sure where you got the "therefore" as they aren't necessarily accurate.
What you mentioned are mostly binary comparison statements.

If the rich get richer, the poor will as a result become poorer.

If the rich get richer faster than the poor get richer, then the poor get relatively poorer.
If you slow down the ability for the rich to get keep getting richer faster than the poor, you will make the poor richer by comparison.

(Therefore, making the rich poorer will make the poor richer.)

The critique, which may be the source of your "therefore", with slowing down the rich to allow the poor to catch up, relatively, is that may slow everyone's gains down for the sake of closing the gap.

If boys are more successful at school, the girls won't learn as well.

If boys are more successful in school, of course the girls wont learn as well, you just said the boys are more successful. So the goal is to make changes that improve the learning of girls.

(Therefore, giving the boys a poorer education will cause the girls to
do better.)

A hypothetical therefore is if you just hamper the boy's learning, the gap will close and the problem disappears in the data, though I haven't seen direct evidence of this being done.
Generally, my understanding of the left wing is that all of your "therefores" are coming from the wrong direction.
Typically, the stated goals are to bolster the bottom side of the comparison to close the gap. It isn't an zero-sum at all. Its entirely a relative comparison. The general idea given is that of these disparities being wrong and in need of correction.
Boys and girls should perform equally in education.
Blacks and whites should enjoy equal success in business.
A deeper part of some of the ideology that leads to statements like what you've provided is the concept of equitable outcome vs equitable opportunity. A lot of these comparisons stem from the concept of an equitable outcome, where everyone is afforded the same outcome regardless of opportunity.
The only difference is with the victim blaming. That, I believe, is very different. The idea being that victim blaming is a common tactic throughout the world as a form of oppression. So, my opinion on this one, is that it is a visceral reaction to try to enact justice. Shield the victim of all blame until the courts can settle it.

Once the society is below some critical level of coherence, there are two lines of motivation:
The first one is take away other people's property and share it inside your group. That is left-wing politics 101 and it has innate appeal for the masses, as Bulgakov noticed.
The second is keeping the stuff you already have to yourself, and ideally growing it at the expense of outsiders. This is right-wing politics 101.
I believe Ancient Greek democracy did work in a fashion where actual state matters were considered by the political system instead of trying to rob or squeeze the fellow compatriot, but that seems rarely happen in modern oligarchic political systems.
